# google project tango debugging

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

What is best way to debug Unity based project Tango Apps that will not run on developers tablet? They compile and are pushed to the tablet but immediately stop running. I have Android studio debugging attached.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the app crashed before the tango service launched. There are several ways to debug:

1. Tango Unity SDK actually has an emulation mode, so when you run a Tango-enabled scene in Unity play mode, it simulates a room and runs the depth related work. You may find the Unity related bugs this way, since Unity will show the error.
2. If nothing is wrong in method 1, then you can look in the Android project log. You can install android studio and its log will show all the logs from the connected android devices, so you can see exactly how your app launches and where the error occur.